# Question on weighting in survey data

Tags: stata, survey

I have household level data wherein I have per household income data (total across members of the household). I have an additional column which states the number of people residing in that household. I have column for probability weight which is the household weight.

Then I also have a column on population weight which is the household size multiplied by probability weight.

In my regression, the dependent variable is per household income. In Stata, should I use aw=population weight or aw=household size for my regression?

My goal is to estimate per household income.